# QGIS 2.18.14 valid option for union tool?

Tags: qgis, union

Using QGIS 2.18.14 there is no satisfying Union method.

The integrated QGIS Union tool generates incorrect outputs if complex polygons (e.g. street network) are used.

The SAGA Union Module does not keep the attributes from both layers.

Is there a valid alternative for these tools that result in a correct union of two layers?

Comment: Could you give an example about incorrect outputs, perhaps with a link to test data that triggers the errors?

Comment: What's wrong with `merge vector layers`?